# How to center a element inside material Ui Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to center element inside Grid in material-ui but it won't center the items.

```
<Grid container direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="center">
    <My Element/>
</Grid>
```

I tried like this but like in below picture it won't center inside the border.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seem to have solved the problem:

```
<Grid style={{display: "flex"}} direction="row"  justify='center' alignItems='center'>
   <My Element/>
<Grid>
```